# How to bind a value from a select?

Tags: aurelia

How can I bind a value selected with aurelia?
I have this select bellow:

```
<select id="user" class="form-control" value.bind="filters[0].value" change.delegate="userDropdownChanged(filters[0].value)">
  <option repeat.for="user of users" model.bind="user.uuid">${user.name}</option>
</select>
```

I tried bind the value, but it is showing the whole list of the select, it is a way to show just the user selected in my h1?

```
<h1 repeat.for="user of users" model.bind="user.uuid">${user.name} </h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do the following:

```
<select value.bind="selectedUser">
  <option repeat.for="user of users" model.bind="user.uuid">${user.name}</option>
</select>
```

The value selected in your `<select>` will be bound to a variable in your viewmodel called `selectedUser`.

You can then bind that to your `<h1>` like so:

```
<h1>${selectedUser.name}</h1>
```